# Generate a dictionary from a list of Records

Tags: dictionary, record, elm

A `BMap` object is a list of `BPair` Elm-Records. How to build a `Dict`ionary containing only those pairs for which `BPair.isEnabled == True`? Ultimately, we need to `Dict.get` at a corresponding `opener` for a given `closer`.

Alternatively, if the Records can themselves be 'queried', then I would rather do that.

```
type alias EnabledPair = (Char, Char) 
type alias EnabledMap  = Dict EnabledPair  -- how to generate this? 

type alias BPair = {
  opener: Char, 
  closer: Char,
  isEnabled: Bool,
  id: Int
}

type alias BMap = List BPair
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you have to:

1. Filter `BMap` to get all `BPair` with `True` in `.isEnabled`
2. Convert all the list items in to Tuples `EnabledPair`
3. Use [Dict.fromList](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Dict#fromList) to convert that to Dictionary
4. Now you can use [Dict.get](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Dict#get) to retrieve `Maybe EnabledPair`

Please consider this example:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Dict exposing (Dict)


type alias EnabledPair = (Char, Char) 


type alias EnabledMap = Dict Char EnabledPair


type alias BPair = {
  opener: Char, 
  closer: Char,
  isEnabled: Bool,
  id: Int
}


type alias BMap = List BPair


testList : BMap
testList =
  [ BPair '(' ')' True 1
  , BPair '{' '}' False 2
  , BPair '[' ']' True 3
  , BPair '<' '>' False 4
  ]


main =
  testList
  |> List.filter (\{isEnabled} -> isEnabled == True)
  |> List.map (\{opener, closer} -> (opener, closer))
  |> Dict.fromList
   -- Dict.get will always return Maybe Char, so you have to handle that
  |> Dict.get '{'
  |> show
```

Comment: Very nice! And the alternative of directly extracting it from the records - is that even possible?

Comment: @lifebalance I'm afraid, there's no "better" way. Elm doesn't allow you to simply get an item from an array-like structure, there's always branching with `Maybe` and as far as I know, this is a design decision. Using `List.head` is okay.

Answer (score 1):

This version uses `List.Extra`'s `find` function to do it even more concisely. Thanks to [Nick H](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/IgEnSRRcTkc) for this.

```
import List.Extra as ListX

matchEnabledOpenr: Char -> BPair -> Bool
matchEnabledOpenr o bp =
  bp.isEnabled && bp.opener == o


getClosr: Char -> List BPair -> Maybe Char
getClosr o bmap =
  ListX.find (matchEnabledOpenr o) bmap
    |> Maybe.map .closer
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrasting style to the accepted answer, here's an approach which avoids generating a dictionary altogether.

```
matchEnabledOpenr: Char -> BPair -> Maybe Char
matchEnabledOpenr o bp = 
  case bp.isEnabled of
    True -> 
      if bp.opener == o then 
        Just bp.closer 
      else 
        Nothing 
    False -> 
        Nothing

getClosr: Char -> List BPair -> Maybe Char 
getClosr o bm =  
  List.head (List.filterMap (matchEnabledOpenr o) bm )
```